# How can public APIs be secured?

Tags: http, web-services, security, api-design

I'd like some help to understand how a public API can be secured.

I'm building a cloud service, which offers a SaaS app, that is my core product and is now ready. But I also want to give the users the ability to extend their experience by including my service in their products. So I build a basic API with an API Key that the user can generate and use in their projects.

I know that API Keys are not meant to be secure, but I believe that I need to provide something to  secure user data from attackers.
So I came across API domain filtering and permissions.

Since my endpoints are just a few I don't need permissions but I think that allowing the users to specify which domain names are allowed to interact with their API endpoints is the way for another level of security.

The point is that the 'Host' header of a request can be spoofed so how can I properly check if the request domain match one of the domains specified by the API user?

My API Key is generated by an hashing function and encoded, only at the moment of creation the Key is shown to the user and only the hash is saved in the database. I also advice the user to keep his API Key secure.

In my approach to check the request domain I use the "Host" header but it can be spoofed, so it doesn't feel like ad additional security level.

So are there any best practices to secure public APIs?
Do you have any advice for my implementation?
Any suggestion on how to check the request domain?

Answer (score 0):

API keys (or tokens) are not insecure per se, as long as they are kept secure. Security can be increased as follows:

- Use long keys with many different characters.
- Reduce the lifetime of the key (or token). This increases the probability that if someone somehow and sometime sees a key without permission, it will no longer work. However, the right balance is also required here, because the new key must be delivered to the user and this is fraught with risk.
- Key/Token blacklist in case something can no longer be considered secure.
- IP whitelisting of the requesting clients (usually only implementable if the clients have static IP addresses like other servers).

I don't really understand the host header thing you mentioned. The hostname refers to your API endpoint (or that of your users). What is the point of spoofing it? The client itself, which makes the request and is potentially a threat, cannot be identified by a hostname, but only by its IP address and the HTTP headers. The latter, however, can be manipulated at will, as you have already correctly pointed out.